# Alphapose running into error RuntimeError: shape '[32, 3, 3, 3]' is invalid for input of size 255

Tags: google-colaboratory

I try the below code:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/tugstugi/dl-colab-notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/AlphaPose.ipynb#scrollTo=tacNMM2Ue2Rt

but it wont work when I run it. It shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 50, in <module>
    det_loader = DetectionLoader(data_loader, batchSize=args.detbatch).start()
  File "/content/AlphaPose/dataloader.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.det_model.load_weights('models/yolo/yolov3-spp.weights')
  File "/content/AlphaPose/yolo/darknet.py", line 488, in load_weights
    conv_weights = conv_weights.view_as(conv.weight.data)
RuntimeError: shape '[32, 3, 3, 3]' is invalid for input of size 255
```